# Selenium java While loop to test multiple websites

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop

I am still very new in Selenium Scripting, I have written a script that checks the presences of a header and a footer element on the Home page (that works well). I want to automate this script to do the test on all of the pages of my website.
But I am stuck, can anyone please help?
The code below just checks for the presence of the logo.
How do I tell Selenium, get the first website, then the second one?

I taught something like this :

```
   String Home = ("http://website.com");
/*I wish I could do
```

String Home = driver.get("http://192.168.10.16:8029/uneo-institutional/?page=home");*/

```
    String Live = ("http://website.com");
    String Inform = ("http://website.com");
    String Help = ("http://website.com");
    
    String[] pages= {Home,Live,Inform,Help};

    for (String Page: pages){
        System.out.println("----------HEADER----------");
        //Start working on the header elements one by one with output
        // check if the logo is present
        System.out.println("Is the logo present:");
        System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'tq-logo-m')]//img")).size() != 0);
        
        //Space
        System.out.println(" ");    
    }
```

Comment: Use `for` loop instead of `while`

Comment: for (String page: pages) { // this code will be executed for each page }

Comment: what do you want to check on all websites?

Comment: @NorayrSargsyan The presence of the Header and the footer + all the elements inside. In a none static way, so that even if more elements are added it won't impact the code.

Answer (score 1):

for (String Page: pages)

```
    {
        driver.get(Page)
//and the rest of the code
```

}